# Two ways to view the three-sphere

Tags: hopf-fibration

Think of the three-sphere as given by $\lbrace|z|^2+|w|^2=1, \;z,w\in \mathbb{C}^2\rbrace$. We can regard it in terms of Hopf coordinates
\begin{align*}
z&= \cos(\theta/2)e^{i(\phi+\psi)}\\
w&= \sin(\theta/2)e^{i\psi}
\end{align*}
These coordinates are adapted to the interpretation of $S^3$ as a torus fibration over an interval where the $\psi$ cycle degenerates at $\theta=0$ while the $\phi+\psi$ degenerates at $\theta=\pi$.

Now, we can also think of $S^3$ in the above coordinates as the usual circle bundle over an $S^2$ with projection
$$p(z,w)=(v,x)=(2zw^*,|z|^2-|w|^2)=(sin(\theta)e^{i\phi},cos(\theta))$$
where $v\in\mathbb{C},x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|v|^2+x^2=1$. As the phase $e^{i\psi}$ drops out, the fiber of this map is a circle parameterized by $\psi$

My confusion now is as follows: from the torus fibration description it appears that the $\psi$ circle degenerates at $\theta=\pi$, while from the circle bundle perspective over $S^2$ it seems $\psi$ truly plays the role of the Hopf circle, i.e. it degenerates nowhere.
Can somebody point out how to resolve the apparent contradiction between these two descriptions?